# Render or convert Html to 'formatted' Text (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, html, string, html-encode

I'm importing some data from another test/bug tracking tool into tfs, and I would like to convert it's description, which is in simple HTML, so a plain string, where the 'layout' of the HTML is preserved.

For example:

```
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>Log on with user Acme &amp; Co.</li>
    <li>Navigate to the details tab</li>
    <li>Check the official name</li>
  </ol>
  <br>
  <br>
  Expected Result:<br>
  official name is filled in<br>
  <br>
  Actual Result:<br>
  The &amp;-sign is not shown correctly<br>
  See attachement.
</body>
```

Would become plain text with newlines inserted and HTML-entities translated like:

```
1. Log on with user Acme & Co.
2. Navigate to the details tab
3. Check the official name

Expected Result:
official name is filled in

Actual Result:
The &-sign is not shown correctly
See attachment
```

I can currently replace some tags with newlines using a regex and strip the rest, but replacing the HTML-entities and stuff like `<ol>` and `<ul>` seemed like I'm re-inventing something (browser?). So I was wondering if someone has done this before me. I can't find it using Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, once I got more comfortable with TFS, I customized the work item type to include a new HTML Field, and just copied the contents into that field.

This solution was so much better, because we could now see the intended formatting of the field.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than regex, you could try loading it into the [HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)? If it was xhtml, then an xslt transformation might be a good option.