# ASP.NET Regex Control

Tags: asp.net, regex

I am doing string matching in ASP.NET C#, I have to convert HTML and `.aspx` page into plain text format (like browser view text), in that HTML page I'm having `<style>`, `<javascript>` and etc. I'm using `Regex.Replace` method.

```
//Removing JavaScripts
str = Regex.Replace(str, "<script.*?>.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//For Link Title
string regex = @"(?<=<title.*>)([\s\S]*)(?=</title>)";
Regex ex = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string title = ex.Match(str).Value.Trim();

//Removing Html Tags
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "<.*?>", "");
str = str.Replace("\r\n", "");
```

Comment: Do you mean you have to display it rendered/parsed like a browser does ?

Comment: I don't really follow your question can you expand on it? You mention you are using regex.replace, are you having problems with this?

Comment: Regex is the *wrong* tool for parsing HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: What are the problems you are facing? You need to expand your question, Nobody will understand your question if you do not supply the details

Comment: just i have to change the html text like a browser viewable text... by using regex control....

Comment: Lots of ideas [in this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731649/how-can-i-convert-html-to-text-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Regex to strip HTML. You need an HTML parsing library. I've used the HTML Agility Pack successfully in the past.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/