# wget without HTML tags

Tags: http, curl, wget, lynx

Is there a way to get body of an html page, without the html tags?

curl and wget return the response, but contain HTML tags. We can strip the tags using sed and awk, but I am looking for an existing tool which could do it without sed and awk.

lynx is an option, but it does not come pre-installed.

Thanks !!

Comment: Duplicate to [How to get text of a page using wget without html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42636/9097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the aversion to installing an appropriate tool?

As an alternative to lynx, try [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/), e.g.

```
w3m -dump http://google.com
```

Comment: I don't have an aversion towards installing a tool. Just need to know if there is an existing tool before installing any other package

Answer (score 0):

[Converting HTML to plain text in PHP for e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884550/converting-html-to-plain-text-in-php-for-e-mail) lists a few tools, as does [How can I Convert HTML to Text in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731649/how-can-i-convert-html-to-text-in-c) . However, if `lynx -dump` does what you want then that may the best tool to install.