# how to strip all html tags and special characters from string using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work as asp.net developer using C#, I receive text like this from the client:

```
> &lt;p&gt;&lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.vogue.co.uk/person/kate-winslet&quot;&gt;KATE
> WINSLET&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;has given birth to a 9lb baby boy. The
> Oscar-winning actress welcomed the baby with her husband Ned Rocknroll
> at a hospital in Sussex.&lt;/p&gt;
> 
> &lt;p&gt;&amp;quot;Kate had &amp;#39;Baby Boy Winslet&amp;#39; on
> Saturday at an NHS Hospital,&amp;quot; Winslet&amp;#39;s spokeswoman
> said, adding that the family were &amp;quot;thrilled to
> bits&amp;quot;.&lt;/p&gt;
> 
> &lt;p&gt;The announcement suggests that the child might bear his
> mother&amp;#39;s surname, rather than his father&amp;#39;s slightly
> more unusual moniker.&lt;/p&gt;
> 
> &lt;p&gt;The baby is Winslet&amp;#39;s third - she is already mother
> to Mia, 13, and Joe, eight, &amp;nbsp;from previous relationships -
> and her husband&amp;#39;s first. They met on Necker Island, owned by
> Rocknroll&amp;#39;s uncle, Richard Branson, and&lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.vogue.co.uk/news/2013/kate-winslet-married-to-ned-rocknroller---wedding-details&quot;&gt;married almost a year ago&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;in New York.&lt;/p&gt;
```

I need a way to extract the real text without tags and special characters using sql server 2008 or above ??

Comment: Are you constrained to use SQL for this? It would probably be more suited to be handled in the application.

Comment: @bendataclear If there are a way to handle it in the application layer, I would like to use it..

Comment: @bendataclear I think you are being too defensive. SQL is unsuitable for this, it _must_ be done in the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can suggest is to use a .net HTML parser or such which is wrapped in a SQL CLR function. Or to wrap the regex in SQL CLR if you want.

Note regex limitations: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Raw SQL language won't do it: it is not a string (or HTML) processing language

Comment: Since he is developing in C# there is no need for a CLR wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same requirement (to remove HTML tags and entities) so developed this function in SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CTU_FN_StripHTML (@dirtyText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
-- Cleaned Text
DECLARE @cleanText NVARCHAR(MAX)=RTRIM(LTRIM(@dirtyText));
-- HTML Tags
DECLARE @tagStart SMALLINT =PATINDEX('%<%>%', @cleanText);
DECLARE @tagEnd SMALLINT;
DECLARE @tagLength SMALLINT;
-- HTML Entities
DECLARE @entityStart SMALLINT =PATINDEX('%&%;%', @cleanText);
DECLARE @entityEnd SMALLINT;
DECLARE @entityLength SMALLINT;
WHILE @tagStart > 0
    OR 
    @entityStart > 0
BEGIN
-- Remove HTML Tag 
SET @tagStart=PATINDEX('%<%>%', @cleanText);
IF @tagStart > 0 
BEGIN
SET @tagEnd=CHARINDEX('>', @cleanText, @tagStart);
SET @tagLength=(@tagEnd - @tagStart) + 1;
SET @cleanText=STUFF(@cleanText, @tagStart, @tagLength, '');
END;
-- Remove HTML Entity
SET @entityStart=PATINDEX('%&%;%', @cleanText);
IF @entityStart > 0 
BEGIN
SET @entityEnd=CHARINDEX(';', @cleanText, @entityStart);
SET @entityLength=(@entityEnd - @entityStart) + 1;
SET @cleanText=STUFF(@cleanText, @entityStart, @entityLength, '');
END;
END;

SET @cleanText = RTRIM(LTRIM(@cleanText))
RETURN @cleanText;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML is so complex it's a very bad idea to do this without an HTML Parser.

You might be interested in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731649/how-can-i-convert-html-to-text-in-c).
The answer that's accepted there is to just use Lynx via the command line and dump the output to a file.
If you can do it outside the users page-load it might be the best option.

Comment: umm, I think I need simpler solution

Comment: @dotWasim The problem is, it will always be a sliding scale between simple and reliable, there won't be a simple solution that can take everything into account. You can make a basic function to remove everything between tags but this won't take into account the codes.

Comment: thanks, I don't need any code inside the tags.. anyway I coded it using regix for now

Comment: @dotWasim I am reminded of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1281901

Comment: @bendataclear I just take first 400 characters from the text to display it as sample and then uses can click read more button to read the whole news.. so what I need is simple and I don't need to make it complex..