# .NET Imap Library with Plain Text conversion

Tags: .net, imap, libraries

Looking for a free/opensource imap library capable of doing auto-conversion from html to plain text (or, even better, saving a mail as text as in "Save As .txt" in Outlook) (like Mailbee's `BodyAsPlainText` which is not free though).

Comment: I can give you some C++ source that did the conversion well enough; only 200 lines but it takes HTML as input, it doesn't speak IMAP. It's not a proper answer but maybe it helps.

Comment: @arnt thanks, i'm too lazy to rewrite the code though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, decided to stick with S22 along with this HtmlAbilityPack sample to convert the html to plain text:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/62772#52179

Comment: An variation to this is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/731649/how-can-i-convert-html-to-text-in-c#25178738 which handles white-space in a better manner.