# HOW TO Convert HTML to plain-text while retaining Tabs and other valid plain-text layout

Tags: .net, regex, html-to-text

[WRT this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732110/44080), pleas how can we adapt it to **retain** **tabs** and other *valid* plain-text **layout**

Referenced solution:

```
 public static string StripHTML(string HTMLText, bool decode = true)
        {
            Regex reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            var stripped = reg.Replace(HTMLText, "");
            return decode ? HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(stripped) : stripped;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, it does preserve tabs and newlines

```
void Main()
{
    var html = "<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\tBody text!\n\t</body>\n</html>";

    StripHTML(html).Dump(); //Prints "\n\t\n\t\tBody text!\n\t\n
}

public static string StripHTML(string HTMLText, bool decode = true)
{
  Regex reg = new Regex("<[^>]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  var stripped = reg.Replace(HTMLText, "");
    return decode ? HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(stripped) : stripped;
}
```