# render string to show text with actual styles(break, bold etc)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, string

I am showing email message body in textbox which is containing html tags in it and showing all tags as it but i want to render it and show actual formatted text. The message body is a string type but was originally a html document sent in email.

Output I am getting:

> [image]

What I want:

> [image]

When I use:

```
 body = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(body);
 TxtBodyText.Text = body;
```

Then it converts < and > to &lt, &gt etc but i wanna display formatted text. Also tried **HtmlAgilityPack**'s Entitize method but no success. Is it possible to do so?

Please help!!

Comment: Why is it rendered in a textbox ? Does it have to be editable ? If yes you need to use some rich text editing component

Comment: @klugjo not editing at the moment but planning to do in future.

Comment: Editing HTML as if it was just a bunch of text with some styles is a very complex subject. I suggest you find yourself a wysiwyg editor of some sort and use that in your project

Comment: take a look here for inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731649/how-can-i-convert-html-to-text-in-c

Comment: @klugjo and Kevin thanks you both for help will try these suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render HTML content inside a text box or text area. You need to use a div or an editable div.

Below is an example-

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    Hi <b>Cheryl</b>,<br/><br/><br/>
    Thank you for your order. Your project ID is C00031. Your invoice is attached.
</div>
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/7225/

Comment: I added string to innertext of div but still showing tags

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Also, you don't need <html>, <head> and <body> tags

Comment: gotcha! thanks for your help need to add string to innerhtml of div and it worked for now

Comment: Glad it worked for you